# Regression question (details inside). Measuring the incremental impact on the dependent variable of one category over other categories

Tags: regression

Formulate a regression equation you would use to test for the differences in ROE between firms that used tier 1 investment banks as their advisors and those that used tier 2 or tier 3 banks (note: tier 2 and tier 3 banks are separate categories). Please define all variables you use in your regression equation.

Here's what I'm thinking.. not sure:
ROE = a + b1(tier2) + b2(tier3), where tier2 and tier3 are dummy variables

Alternatively I'm considering the following:
ROE = a +b1(tier1) + b2(tier2tier3), where tier2tier3 is set to 0 if the bank is neither part of tier 1 or tier 2

Could you please explain the logic behind the best answer? We also need to discuss the relationship between the coefficients (and their statistical significance) of these regressions and the t-tests for the differences in mean ROEs.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand why tier2tier3 = 0 if the bank is neither part of tier 1 or tier 2?